# Staging URL for web development

Tags: staging-server

Just wondered if anyone has a painless way of setting up a staging URL for website development. I often use Heart Internet, but the temporary URLs provided (ie ipaddress/domainreference) do not work with EE installations. In the past I've changed the domain ref to a staging domain, and got the client to point a subdomain to the new IP address. However, I'm not sure if Heart are allowing this now. I can also setup a hosts config locally, but that's makes client reviews awkward. Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) useful. It allows you to replace the config.php file with a multi-environment setup that allows you to create sets of configuration items for each environment. From there it's just a matter of putting the right settings for the staging server.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a painless method and this seems way over my head unfortunately.

Comment: In that case, REElocate might be helpful for you: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate